# Is there a way to clear the printed results and then run a function on the same line?

Tags: python

I am kinda new to python and I want to print a message and then after that delete that message and run a function that displays a list.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Let's say I want to print "Hello world" and then I want to wait for a few seconds and after all of that I want to run a function called "menuFeature" which has already been defined
can you write an example for something like that? 
I understood everything except for the clearing part

Answer (score 0):

To clear the `Python` interpreter, you can use `os.system()` and execute a `CLI` command to clear the console like that:

```
import system
os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
```

If you are on Windows, the command would be `cls`, on Linux it's `clear`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```py
import os
def func():
    print([1,2,3,4])
print("Hello")
os.system("cls")
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using a Windows shell, like CMD, it is possible but it is not the best way to do so. Eg:

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
print("Hello")
input()
clear()
print("World")
```

This code prints `hello` in the first line. Then on pressing enter, it clears the terminal and prints `world`. Though this won't work if you are trying to clear a specific line.

A better way would be to use `tkinter`.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
label1 = Label(tk, text="Numeric parameters")
label1.pack()
def a():
    global label1
    label1.configure(text="Hello")
button1 = Button(tk, command=a, text="Click Me")
button1.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

This creates a GUI with a `Click Me` button that changes the text in the label on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to print a message and then after that delete that message and run a function that displays a list.
```

Is this what you want like that?

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('50x20')

def menuFeature():
    lbl_change.configure(text='I am back again') 
    root.after(5000, menuFeature)
      
     
lbl_change = tk.Label(root, text='Hello World', width=15, fg='white', bg='red')
lbl_change.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.after(5000, menuFeature)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]